# How can I prove that the following limes of the supremum of probability induces the limes of variance?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, variance

Imagine I have a given sample $X_1, \ldots, X_T$ of some process; Also the realisations are identically distributed and we denote with $\mathbb E(X_1)=\mu$

Imagine I bootstrap it the standard way, so choose $T$ realisations $X_{i_1},\ldots,X_{i_T}$ randomly from the given sample with replacement;
Denote the bootstrap sample as $X_1^*,\ldots,X_T^*$ and denote with $\bar{X}_n$ the mean of the original sample and $\bar{X}_n^*$ the mean of the bootstrap sample;

Now I know that:

$$\sup_x\left\vert \mathbb P\left(\sqrt{T}(\bar{X}_n^*-\bar{X}_n)\leq x \mid X_1,\ldots,X_T\right)-\mathbb P\left(\sqrt{T}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\leq x\right) \right \vert \to 0$$ almost surely as $T$ goes to infinity;

Now I want to show that:

$$\left\vert\operatorname{Var}^*\bigg(\sqrt{T}(\bar{X}_n^*-\bar{X}_n)\bigg)-\operatorname{Var}\bigg(\sqrt{T}(\bar{X}_n-\mu)\bigg) \right \vert\to 0$$ almost surely as $T$ goes to infinity;

here $\operatorname{Var}^*(\cdot)$ denotes the variance operator of the resampling distribution
$P^∗$ conditional on our original sample $X_1,\ldots,X_T$.

We see it is very similar- so it is mostly only about turning the supremum of probabilities into a variance;

But how can I do it?

Comment: Well in German language limes means the limit; Actually it is Latin and means limit; So I'm pretty sure that "lim" stands for limes as well; But I didn't know that this words doesn't exist in English - sorry

Comment: But do you maybe want to help me with the question? :-) Still looking for anyone able to answer it

Comment: Sure, I'm looking at the problem now. I got distracted by something else.

Comment: [As an aside](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limes#Etymology_and_sentiment)

Comment: Ah so it actually stands for limit although limit comes from limes... :D Very interesting - learned something